# The use of pivot data to calculate a column

Tags: t-sql, pivot, calculation

I have a PIVOT

```
SELECT         txtSchoolID, intSubjectID, txtPreName, txtSurname, txtForm, [636] AS Effort, [637] AS Focus, [638] AS Participation, [639] AS Groupwork, [640] AS Rigour, [641] AS Curiosity, [642] AS Initiative,
                [643] AS SelfOrganisation, [644] as Perserverance       

FROM         (SELECT  txtSchoolID, intSubjectID, intGradeTransposeValue, intGradeID, txtForm, txtPreName, txtSurname FROM VwReportsManagementAcademicReports 
                WHERE (intReportCycleID = 142) AND (intReportProgress = 1)) p
PIVOT
(AVG        (intGradeTransposeValue)
FOR intGradeID IN ([636], [637], [638], [639], [640], [641], [642], [643], [644] )
) AS pvt
```

I need to now use values from my pivot to produce additional columns. I want to create a column called FocusLH and populate it with a value based on a calculation. The calculation is - if the result of Effort+Focus=2 then assign the value 5 in FocusLH, if the result is 3 assigns the value 4 etc etc

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was putting the CASE statement in the wrong place and needed to use the intGradeID's instead of the alias. This works now

```
SELECT         txtSchoolID, intSubjectID, txtPreName, txtSurname, txtForm, [636] AS Effort, [637] AS Focus, [638] AS Participation, [639] AS Groupwork, [640] AS Rigour, [641] AS Curiosity, [642] AS Initiative,
                [643] AS SelfOrganisation, [644] as Perserverance,       
        CASE WHEN [636] + [637] = 2 THEN 5 
        WHEN [636] + [637] =3 THEN 4 
        WHEN [636] + [637] =4 THEN 3 
        WHEN [636] + [637] =5 THEN 2         
        ELSE NULL END AS FocusLH 
FROM         (SELECT  txtSchoolID, intSubjectID, intGradeTransposeValue, intGradeID, txtForm, txtPreName, txtSurname                
                FROM VwReportsManagementAcademicReports 
                WHERE (intReportCycleID = 142) AND (intReportProgress = 1)) p
PIVOT
(MAX        (intGradeTransposeValue)
FOR intGradeID IN ([636], [637], [638], [639], [640], [641], [642], [643], [644] )
) AS pvt
```